# BST Insert Method JS Getting an Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```js
 class Node {
constructor(val) {
this.value = val;
this.left = null;
this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
constructor() {
this.root = null;
}

insert(val) {
    var node = new Node(val);
    if(!this.root) {
      this.root = node;
      return this;
    } else{
       var root = this.root;
      while(root) {
         if(val === root.value) return undefined;
          if(val < root.value) {
             if(!root.left) {
              root.left = node;
               return this;
             } else{
               root = root.left;
             }
          } else if(val > root.value) {
                if(!root.right) {
                  root.right = node;
                  return this;
                } else{
                  root = root.right;
                }
              }
           }
      }
   }
}

   var bts = new BinarySearchTree();
   
   bts.insert(100);
```

I get an infinite loop most of the time with this method, I have no idea why, can anybody please help me to find the error in my code, Sometime this methods works fine, but other times an infinite loop. Thank you

Comment: Instead of this if(!root.left) you should use if(root.left===null) and same goes for  if(!root.right). And, do you have example where it is going in infinite loop?

Comment: Please provide an example with which we can reproduce the problem. The code you have provided cannot run infinitely unless you modify the data structure in another way -- not presented in this code. Do you have and call other methods?

Comment: I really appreciate your time, I just changed from if(!root.right) to if(root.right === null) and same for if(!root.left) to if(root.left === null). And invoked the insert method with  bts.insert(100);  bts.insert(50);            but again the browser went in infinite loop.

Comment: I tried the exact same code on Window and Macbook pro 16, just might to expect different results, but on both i get the browser with the Infinite Loop.

Comment: I have run your code with `bts.insert(100); bts.insert(50);` and it appears to be working just fine. I don't think the issue is an infinite loop, or the issue is occurring in code not present in your question. Unless you can provide additional details, this question will probably be closed.